# How to set fix header for datatables library in symfony project with webpack

Tags: symfony, webpack, datatables

I use Symfony with webpack and faced with problem when add new packeg `datatables`. I read many post about problem exclude this library and only one way give me successful result wihout error by `import`

package.json

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.8.2",
    "@symfony/webpack-encore": "^0.30.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "core-js": "^3.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.2",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "webpack-notifier": "^1.6.0"
  },
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev-server": "encore dev-server",
    "dev": "encore dev",
    "watch": "encore dev --watch",
    "build": "encore production --progress"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "datatables.net": "^1.10.21",
    "datatables.net-autofill-bs4": "^2.3.5",
    "datatables.net-bs4": "^1.10.21",
    "datatables.net-buttons-bs4": "^1.6.3",
    "datatables.net-colreorder-bs4": "^1.5.2",
    "datatables.net-dt": "^1.10.21",
    "datatables.net-fixedcolumns-bs4": "^3.3.1",
    "datatables.net-fixedheader-bs4": "^3.1.7",
    "datatables.net-keytable-bs4": "^2.5.2",
    "datatables.net-responsive-bs4": "^2.2.5",
    "datatables.net-rowgroup-bs4": "^1.1.2",
    "datatables.net-rowreorder-bs4": "^1.2.7",
    "datatables.net-scroller-bs4": "^2.0.2",
    "datatables.net-searchpanes-bs4": "^1.1.1",
    "datatables.net-select-bs4": "^1.3.1",
    "file-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "url-loader": "^1.1.2"
  }
}
```

app.js

```
import '../css/app.scss';
import * as dt_bs4 from 'datatables.net-bs4'
import * as fh_bs from 'datatables.net-fixedheader-bs4';

require('@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css');
require('datatables.net-dt/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css');
require('@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all.js');

const $  = require( 'jquery' );
global.$ = global.jQuery = $;
require('bootstrap');
```

when I try followed to documentation

```
var $ = require( 'jquery' );
require( 'datatables.net-bs4' )( window, $ );
require( 'datatables.net-fixedheader-bs4' )( window, $ );
```

I faced with error `TypeError: Cannot set property '$' of undefined`

my_file.js

```
import list from './parts/sort.js';

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    list();
});
```

sort.js

```
export default function list() {

    $('#example').dataTable({
        fixedHeader: true
    });   
}
```

how to correct include this library?